# Why isn't my variable showing as defined?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to make "Rock, Paper, Scissors" as my second program. I keep encountering an error,

```py
"Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/cabox/workspace/main.py", line 118, in <module>
  File "/home/cabox/workspace/main.py", line 48, in Rock_Paper_Scissors
    else:
NameError: name 'rps_choice' is not defined"
```

And here's the code.

```
import time
import random

def Rock_Paper_Scissors():
  print("Welcome to the \"Rock, Paper, Scissors\" game!")

  time.sleep(2)

  def rps_input():
    while True:
      rps_choice = input("Say \"Rock\", \"Paper\", or \"Scissors\" to get started: ")

      if rps_choice.upper() == "ROCK":
        print("Great! You chose", rps_choice.upper(), end='')
        print("! The computer picked...")
        return rps_choice.upper()
      if rps_choice.upper() == "PAPER":
        print("Great! You chose", rps_choice.upper(), end='')
        print("! The computer picked...")
        return rps_choice.upper()
      if rps_choice.upper() == "SCISSORS":
        print("Great! You chose", rps_choice.upper(), end='')
        print("! The computer picked...")
        return rps_choice.upper()
      
      else:
        print("Sorry, please say \"Rock\", \"Paper\", or \"Scissors.\"")

        time.sleep(2)

        print("\n")

  rps_input()

  time.sleep(2)

  rps_list = ["ROCK","PAPER","SCISSORS"]

  rps_random = random.choice(rps_list)
  print(rps_random, end='')
  print("!")

  time.sleep(2)

  if rps_choice == rps_random:
    print("You both picked the same. Please try again.")
    rps_input()
  else:

    if rps_choice == "ROCK":

      if rps_random == "PAPER":
        print("The computer's paper beats your rock.")

        time.sleep(2)

        print("You LOSE.")
      if rps_random == "SCISSORS":
        print("Your rock beats the computer's scissors!")

        time.sleep(2)

        print("You WIN.")
    if rps_choice == "PAPER":

      if rps_random == "ROCK":
        print("Your paper beats the computer's rock!")

        time.sleep(2)

        print("You WIN.")
      if rps_random == "SCISSORS":
        print("The computer's scissors beats your paper.")

        time.sleep(2)

        print("You LOSE.")
      
    else:
      
      if rps_random == "ROCK":
        print("The computer's rock beats your scissors.")

        time.sleep(2)

        print("You LOSE.")
      if rps_random == "PAPER":
        print("Your scissors beat the computer's paper.")

        time.sleep(2)

        print("You WIN.")

  time.sleep(2)

  def RPS_Reset_Quit():
    rq = input("Restart or quit? (R/Q): ")
    if rq.lower() == "r":
      print("\n")
      Rock_Paper_Scissors()
    if rq.lower() == "q":
      print("Quiting...")

      time.sleep(2)

      quit()
    else:
      print("Sorry, please say either R or Q.")

      time.sleep(2)

      RPS_Reset_Quit()
  RPS_Reset_Quit()

Rock_Paper_Scissors()
```

As you can maybe see, my variable, `rps_choice`, is not defined, even though it was defined and returned from the `rps_input()` function. I really have no clue as to why this is happening.

Comment: you never assign the return value of `rps_input` to a variable - `rps_choice == rps_input()`

Comment: Mandatory link to [Ned Batchelder](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html)

Answer (score 5):

You meant to capture the returned value in `rps_choice`:

```py
rps_choice = rps_input()
```

Also, I see you have `rps_input()` called on two different lines. Both these lines will need updating.

Comment: Ok, thanks, Nice name btw. Please can you update your error traceback. It does not reflect the error.

Answer (score 3):

Because you defined it inside the function `rps_input()` so it belongs only to that function. Imagine it as a hierarchy, the variables from downer scopes can access the variables from upper scopes but it doesn't go the other way.